# Why can't mysqli_fetch_object be re-used for the same query?

Tags: php, mysqli

So I noticed that if I call `mysqli_fetch_object($A)` for the same query `$A` more than once I get this error message:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in [file] on [line]

For example if I did this:

```
// This returns a single row
$A = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT .. FROM ... WHERE ..."); 

echo mysqli_fetch_object($A)->item; // This works fine
echo mysqli_fetch_object($A)->item2; // Error on this line
```

I'm curious why you cannot do this, is their a specific reason?

**Notice:**

I'm aware that you can fix this problem by doing the following:

```
$obj = mysqli_fetch_object($A);

echo $obj->item; 
echo $obj->item2;
```

Comment: you have only 1 row in you record set, this is why second fetch cannot get new row

Comment: because that's what it does. It moves to the next row. once there are no more rows, what would you expect it to do ?

Comment: @njzk2 I didn't expect it to move to the next row. And hence get the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code example in the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-object-examples) I suppose that you don't have any more rows (in your case only one) so the `mysqli_fetch_object` returns NULL.

`mysqli_fetch_object` doesn't fetch the same row every time it's called. It fetches every consecutive row. If you call it once, it returns the first row, if you call it x times it retuns the x-th row.

That is why the documentation's example works:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

As you can see, the while runs [number of rows] cycles.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I assumed only `fetch_row()` did that.